# How to store inputs in Array (Arduino)

Tags: arrays, function, arduino

I'm a novice in Arduino and I want to use the inputs in an Array to use in a function of multiply but i don't know how. I'm thinking of making another array than dip1 & dip2 to store the bit inputs in the array. Is it right?
Here's my code:

```
int dip1[] = {A0, A1, A2, A3};
int dip2[] = {A4, A5, 2, 3};
int leds[] = {4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};

void setup(){

for (int i=0; i <4; i++){
   pinMode(dip1[i], INPUT);
   digitalWrite(dip1[i], HIGH);
 }

for (int i=0; i <4; i++){
  pinMode(dip2[i], INPUT);
  digitalWrite(dip2[i], HIGH);
 }

for (int i=0; i <8; i++){
  pinMode(leds[i], OUTPUT);
 }
 } 


void loop () {


for (int i =0;i<8;i++)
{
     if (bitRead(multiply(), i)==1){
        digitalWrite(leds[i], HIGH); 
     }
    else{
       digitalWrite(leds[i], LOW); 
     }

     }

}

int multiply () {

    int a = digitalRead(dip1[0,1,2,3]);
    int b = digitalRead(dip2[0,1,2,3]);
    int prod = 0;
    int mpartial = b;

      while (mpartial != 0 ) {
          prod = prod + a;
          mpartial = mpartial - 1;     
    }

    return prod;
    }
```

---

I highly appreciate the help and i know there are lots of error in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not following what you need to do but your expectations for this line are wrong:

```
int a = digitalRead(dip1[0,1,2,3]);
```

`digitalRead()` only takes one argument. If, for some reason, you want to perform artihmentic operations on the result of reading multiple pins, you will have to do it in a loop (as you do in initializing the pins).

```
int a;
for (int i=0; i <4; i++){
   a += digitalRead(dip1[i]);
 }
```

Comment: I see, but arduino verify it smoothly that's why i get the wrong answer.

But can i use the array that I'll be getting on the dip switch  to be the a and b in multiply function? I don't know how to declare the array in it.

Comment: It is difficult to know what to suggest since I can't tell what you need the code to do. You can use an array to store the pin number like you are and then accumulate the states of the switches in a local variable and use that as in my example above. (I probably don't understand what you are trying to accomplish).

Comment: Now i just realized what you want to point out. Thank you very much for your replies! I just read again your example. I'm so sloowww. 

I just want to use the input in the array to be an input in the multiply() function. That's all. I just don't know how to call/declare all the array elements in the dip1 and dip2.
And your example is a great help! Thank you again :)

Comment: Wait, i tried it, there's an error in the line:

    a += digitalWrite(dip1[i]);

 -- At this point in file... what does it mean?

Comment: That was a copy/paste error in my example (fixed). It should have been `digitalRead(dip[i])` since the code is intended to read the state of the pin.

Comment: I didn't notice the read and write thing. foolish me-_- Thank you again, i'll try it!

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to declare the analog pins as output in setup function. its understood to the arduino.